# EF5 how to update parent by adding a new child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

Within a unit test, I'm trying to test updates/deletes/insertion of order items to an order.  It's a 1 to N relationship between an order and orderitems.

I keep receiving the DBUpdateConcurrencyException when I try to add a new child to an existing parent within the controller's update code.

This is the exception: *Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.*

My questions are:
a) What is the correct way to add new items to an existing parent?
a) What is the correct way to delete items to an existing parent?
b) If not, from the exception message, how does one update the Objectstatemanager entries?

Model Code:

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> lstOrderItems { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {
        OrderID = 0;
        ...
        lstOrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    }
}

public class OrderItem
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int? OrderID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderItemID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderID")]
    public virtual Order Orders { get; set; }

    public OrderItem()
    {
        OrderID = 0;
        OrderItemID = 0;
        Orders = new Order();
    }
}
```

Unit Test that populates the order and order items.
**Note:** I previous added the items to this order successfully without an exception.  This unit test test adding a new orderitem (the 4th item) to this order, and it's where I get the exception.

```
     Order oOrder = new Order();
        oOrder.OrderID = TEST_ORDERID;


        OrderItem oItems = new OrderItem();

        #region Add items
        oItems.OrderID = 1;
        oItems.OrderItemID = 1;
        oItems.Orders = oOrder;

        oOrder.lstOrderItems.Add(oItems);

        oItems = new OrderItem();
        oItems.OrderID = 1;
        oItems.OrderItemID = 2;
        oItems.Orders = oOrder;           

        oOrder.lstOrderItems.Add(oItems);

        oItems = new OrderItem();
        oItems.OrderID = 1;
        oItems.OrderItemID = 3;
        oItems.Orders = oOrder;

        oOrder.lstOrderItems.Add(oItems);

        / *** This is the new item ***/
        oItems = new OrderItem();
        oItems.OrderID = 0;
        oItems.OrderItemID = 1000;     // Constant that identifies this is a new orderitem
        oItems.Orders = oOrder;

        oOrder.lstOrderItems.Add(oItems);
```

Controller code that generates the exceptions:

```
public void Update(Order o)
    {
        OrderContext _context = new OrderContext();  // Where OrderContext is derived from DBContext
        try
        {
            bool bAdded = false;

            foreach (var i in o.lstOrderItems)
            {
                i.OrderID = o.OrderID;
            }

            foreach (var i in o.lstOrderItems)
            {
                if (i.OrderItemID == 1000)
                {
                    if (i.Qty > 0)
                    {
                        _context.Entry(i).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
                        i.OrderItemID = 0;  // Not sure if I have to reset this back to 0
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _context.Entry(i).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    if (i.OrderItemID != -1000)
                    {
                        if (i.Qty > 0)
                        {
                            _context.Entry(i).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _context.Entry(i).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _context.Entry(i).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
                    }
                }
            }

            _context.Entry(o).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified; 

            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)_context).ObjectContext;
            objContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, _context.Orders);

            objContext.SaveChanges();    // WHen this line executes, it generates a OptimisticConcurrencyException.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've been working with EF for years and I think never had to work with the entity states. The way to add things to a parent in EF? Get the entity - add a child - SaveChanges(). The way to delete it ? Get it, remove the child - SaveChanges(). Let EF do the entity state tracking for you. But in case you work with detached entities - this might be of interest to you: https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphDiff/ - if you have a parent with children posted back from a site - it will compare against the database and add/remove/modify the children in the collection.

Comment: Spike - are you talking about adding a child to a parent using dbcontext,OrderItem.Add?   When I try that and comment out the Added state line, it throws a exception saying that Primary Key violation, It's trying to add an Order object.